# NPM fails to install Socket.io does it need x-server?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to install socket.io on my linux server using NPM

root@camdev01-dev:# npm install socket.io

(npm:22742): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

OS:ubuntu.11.10 server

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick how to for installing npm on Ubuntu, or any variant of UNIX for that matter

```
$ `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`
```

It is that simple!

So you want to check out the code from git and compile it yourself? Then follow these steps:

```
$ `git clone https://github.com/isaacs/npm`
$ `cd npm`
$ sudo make install
```

Now you can install interesting stuff like socket.io

```
$ npm install socket.io
```

X-server is not a dependency package of Socket.io...

[Dependency packages](https://npmjs.org/browse/depended/socket.io/0/)

Comment: X11Forwarding is On